# Getting data from API and correlating it to the correct month for more than just 1 years time

Tags: swift

I am getting data back from an api which is a list of strings. I have a function that will return the current month and previous months to match the data.

```
data: [null,null,null,null,null,null,"771.6","1618.6","1434.6","1449.64","877.2","431.8","32.65"]
```

This is the response and it has 12 spots for the whole year of data.
Now that we are in 2023 I need to accept more than 12 and return the correct months.

// this was my function to map the data to the correct month and return it

```
func getMonthListFromCurrentTime(len: Int) -> [String] {
            // function to get current time and return a list of every month including current for the year
        let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
        let monthInt = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date())
        let currentMonthsPast = months[..<monthInt] // all months to current
        
        return Array(currentMonthsPast.suffix(len))
    }
```

Now we are in january of 23 I need to be able to accept 13+ months of data from the api and then connect the last piece of data in the array to the current month.

Ex apiResponse = `["1.6","2.4","3.","4.4","5.2","6.9","7.4","8.7","9.6","10","11","12","13"]`

I need to return a list of months that need to be like this

`["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec","Jan"]`

That way the last month in the array is current month

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out a simple solution. since i get back an array of 24 i know I can mod the result by 12 and get the month index into the array.

```
func getMonths(apiDataList: [String?]) -> [String] {
    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "August", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
        var displayMonths = [String]()
        
    for (idx, entry) in apiDataList.enumerated() {
        if entry == nil {continue}
        let monthIdx = idx % 12
            
        displayMonths.append(months[monthIdx])
    }
    return displayMonths
    }
```